# Precompiling Haml-like templates into Underscore templates

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, pug, gulp

I can't stand the traditional HTML syntax. Haml, Slim, Jade are much more readable and concise.

I'm using Backbone which does template rendering clientside. I don't want to burden users forcing them to download. An additional templating library will not increase product value for users. Instead, i would like to precompile templates serverside.

Backbone depends on Underscore and underscore has its own templating engine.

So the question is: how do i precompile templates from any indentation-based language (Haml, Slim, Jade, etc) into Underscore templates? Preferably with Gulp.

Comment: Most JavaScript template systems compile templates to functions and then you execute the function to get your HTML; at least all the ones I've used to it this way. So you should be able to precompile your templates to JavaScript (if your desired template system is at all sane) and do things JST-style. There should be no need to use Underscore templates as an intermediate form.

Comment: @muistooshort, that's awesome! Can you please convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: But it isn't really answer, just a pointer towards a better approach.

Comment: It's the best there is so far, and it does solve my problem.